# Add Random IImage Rotation and Caption Fade-in to jquery.backstretch.captions.js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to add ***random-image-rotation*** and ***fade-in*** to the captions in this *jquery.backstretch.captions.js* script, but I've failed every time. As it is now, only the images fade-in as they rotate sequentially. Please take a look at it. Can they be added?

-Thanks

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

        var items = [
            
            { img: "images/backgrounds/charles-chaplin.jpg", caption: "Charles Chaplin"},
            
            { img: "images/backgrounds/mae-west.jpg", caption: "Mae West"},
            
            { img: "images/backgrounds/greta-garbo.jpg", caption: "Greta Garbo"}
        ];

        var options = {
            fade: 2000,
            duration: 6000
        };

        var images = $.map(items, function(i) { return i.img; });
        var slideshow = $.backstretch(images,options);

        $(window).on("backstretch.show", function(e, instance) {
            var theCaption = items[instance.index].caption;
            var theLink = items[instance.index].link;
            if (theLink) {
                $(".backstretch-caption").html('<a href="'+theLink+'">'+theCaption+'</a>').show().addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            } else {
                $(".backstretch-caption").text(theCaption).show().addClass('animated fadeInUp');
            }
        });
        $(window).on("backstretch.before", function(e, instance) {
            $(".backstretch-caption").hide();
            
        });
});
```